# Cython "Memory Efficient Doubly Linked List"

Tags: python, pointers, linked-list, cython

As an exercise, I am putting together a doubly-linked list using XOR on pointers to facilitate only having to store a single value per node. I'm trying to use Cython which is new to me and I drew up the following pattern quickly without knowing if the features of cython would work as expected

```
cdef class Node:
    def __init__(self, object val, void* prev_xor_next=NULL):
        self.prev_xor_next=prev_xor_next
        self.val=val

    def __repr__(self):
        return str(self.val)

cdef class CurrentNode(Node):
    def __init__(self, Node node, void* prev_ptr=NULL):
        self.node=node
        self.prev_ptr=prev_ptr

    cpdef CurrentNode forward(self):
        if self.node.prev_xor_next:
            return CurrentNode((self.node.prev_xor_next^self.prev_ptr)[0], &self.node)

    cpdef CurrentNode backward(self):
        if self.prev_ptr:
            return CurrentNode(self.prev_ptr[0], (&self.node)^(self.prev_ptr[0]).prev_xor_next)

cdef class XORList:
    cdef Node first, last, current

    cpdef append(self, object val):
        if not first:
            self.first=CurrentNode(Node(val))
            self.last=self.first
            self.current=self.first
        else:
            if last==first:
                self.last=CurrentNode(Node(val))
                self.first.node.prev_xor_next=(&self.last.node)^self.first.prev_ptr
                self.first=self.first.node
                self.last.prev_ptr=&self.first
            else:
                temp=CurrentNode(Node(val))
                self.last.node.prev_xor_next=(&self.temp.node)^self.last.prev_ptr
                self.temp.prev_ptr=&self.last
                self.last=temp

    cpdef reverse(self):
        temp=self.last
        self.last=self.first
        self.first=temp

    def __iter__(self):
        return self

    def __next__(self):
        if not self.current or not self.current.forward():
            self.current=CurrentNode(self.first)
            raise StopIteration()
        ret = self.current
        self.current=self.current.forward()
        return ret

    def __repr__(self):
        cdef str ret =''
        for i in self:
            ret+='<=>'+str(i)
        return ret
```

The problems I've faced include getting pointers to extension types and passing pointers to constructors. The second of which I've found solved by using a static factory method but I've left that out here to hopefully keep the pattern I'm trying clearer.

I've tried replacing Node with a struct yet this leaves me unable to take a python object as the Node's value.

I've looked into PyObject and PyCapsule, but I've had no luck with these either which could simply be due to a lack of understanding of their usage although their base purposes do seem clear.

Is there an approach that allows this pattern using Cython?

Please forgive any logical errors in the code. I haven't tested it and it's just an exercise.

Comment: So the general problem is that anything `def` or `cpdef` (which includes constructors) must be callable from Python, which means you can't pass types not representable as a PyObject. Therefore `cdef` static constructors are the way to go. I'm pretty sure there will be a duplicate asking about this. _However_ pointers are just specialized integers, so you could pass them about as integers to Python (then cast)

Comment: This also looks like a possible reference-counting disaster (although I'm not sure I follow quite well enough to be certain). Every `cdef` class is reference counted, but an xor-ed point won't keep a reference to it alive...

Comment: @DavidW I did also try using uintptr_t and casting while still using __init__ however I preferred the solution in what I think was your answer using a static method. Also, my understanding was that special methods have to be declared as `def`. If you look in `CurrentNode` you'll see I want an actual pointer to a `Node`. This is the current problem I can't address with any of those other changes

Comment: Yes, special methods must be `def`. You should be able to cast a pointer to a node with angle bracket syntax: `<Node>`. However the reference counting is still a problem.

Comment: @DavidW could you elaborate what you're thinking for casting to node? The initial issue is not being able to get a pointer to a Node object so what is there to even cast?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You can cast extension types to-and-from pointers using the angle-bracket cast syntax. It's often worth using the type `PyObject*` which you can `cimport from cpython.object` however you can also go directly to `void*`:

```
from cpython.object cimport PyObject

cdef Node n = Node()
cdef PyObject* nptr1 = <PyObject*>n
cdef void* nptr2 = <void*>n
cdef void* nptr3 = <void*>nptr1
```

To return back to the cdef type:

```
cdef Node new_node = <Node>nptr1
```

The one thing Cython won't let you is:

```
# ERROR: Storing unsafe C derivative of temporary Python reference
cdef PyObject* bad = <PyObject*>Node()
```

It realises that the new `Node` will cease to exist almost as soon as it is made, so the pointer is instantly invalid. In contrast `nptr1`, `nptr2`, and `nptr3` are valid for at least as long as `n` isn't reassigned.

---

Note that you must handle the reference counting for these yourself. You can access the relevant function with `cimport` again: `from cpython.ref cimport Py_XINCREF, Py_XDECREF`. The functions take `PyObject*`, hence why it's useful to use it. If you intend to store one of these pointers then you need to increase the reference count, and you should decrease the reference count when you're done with it.

I don't know exactly what reference counting should be done for your xor-ed list, but you *will need to do it*!

There's potentially a more subtle reference counting problem here too: if you have circular references (for example if `Node` contains a link to `XOrList`) then it'll never get freed. Cython attempts to generate functions that handle circular references for cdef classes however it doesn't (and can't) understand what you're doing with pointers so they will be excluded; it isn't easy to override this behaviour.

Comment: this is a really nice answer. Thank you. I'll +1 and test and accept later. You've also answered another question about PyObject. I'd tried something similar using PyObject and PyCapsule. This makes more sense though

Comment: Your solution worked and I'm satisfied with how it came out overall but I feel like I'm missing something. I haven't tested for memory leaks but the performance is lacking. perhaps you could help with https://stackoverflow.com/q/58617519/7907717